# Bash: add a variable containing 10 lines of data to a penultimate line of a file in bash

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

I'm looking for a one liner that adds a stanza to the penultimate line of a file.

file: sample.conf

```
server {
   a;
   b;
   c;
 }

   /test {
    a;
  }

  /main {
    b;
  }
}
```

i have my new data that i want to append to the penultimate line of the above file sample.conf in variable $var.

```
var="/new {
        k;
        l;
        m;
     }
```

Expected output of a file:

file: sample.conf

```
 server {
       a;
       b;
       c;
     }

       /test {
        a;
      }

      /main {
        b;
      }


      /new {
            k;
            l;
            m;
       }

    }
```

Things i tried:
i added a pattern like #[newblock].

```
sed "/#[newblock]/$var" sample.conf
```

append line before matching the patterm

```
totalCount=$(`wc -l sample.conf`)
penultimate=$((totalCount-1))

sed -n -i "p;{$penultimate}a $var" sample.conf
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `gnu sed`:

```
sed -i "$ i\\
${var//$'\n'/\\$'\n'}" file
```

Check output:

```
cat file
```

```
server {
   a;
   b;
   c;
 }

   /test {
    a;
  }

  /main {
    b;
  }
/new {
        k;
        l;
        m;
     }

}
```

Comment: tested and working like a charm anubhava. Thanks much for the help.

Answer (score 3):

With GNU awk (and most other awks except BSD/OSX awk which doesn't like newlines in strings):

```
$ awk -v var="$var" 'NR>1{print prev} {prev=$0} END{print var ORS prev}' sample.conf
server {
   a;
   b;
   c;
 }

   /test {
    a;
  }

  /main {
    b;
  }
/new {
        k;
        l;
        m;
     }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. i tested this. Its appending the variable to the penultimate line of the file but its printing entire source file contents to the screen. does it not save the file after it appends the data ?

Comment: No, no UNIX tool (except an editor of course) overwrites the input file by default because that would be dangerous to assume that's a reasonable thing to do. Several tools such as GNU awk and GNU sed have options to cause that to happen but you need to specify the appropriate option on the command line, e.g. `awk -i infile 'script' file` or `sed -i 'script' file`. The common approach that works with all tools is just to write the output to a temp file and then overwrite the original file with that temp file, e.g. `awk 'script' file > tmp && mv tmp file`.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
cat <<EOF | sed -i '$e cat /dev/stdin' file
$var
EOF
```

Put the contents of the `$var` in a here-document and using the `e` command evaluate the `cat` command of it before printing the last line of the file.

Of course the `$var` does not need to be created in the first place:

```
cat <<\! | sed -i '$e cat /dev/stdin' file
lines
before
the 
last 
line
!
```

Or variable(s) and text can be interwoven:

```
cat <<EOF | sed -i '$e cat /dev/stdin' file
this is \$var $var
this is \$var again $var
EOF
```

Finally, as it is nearly Xmas!:

```
sed -i 'N;$s/\n/&'"${var//$'\n'/&}"'&/;P;D' file
```